# Why does this recursion MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n] = 2; end?

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica, iteration

I don't understand, why does this recursion end:

```
In[27]:= MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n] = 2;
MyFunc[3]

Out[28]= 2
```

Shouldn't it be endless

```
MyFunc[3]
MyFunc[3] = 2
(MyFunc[3] = 2) = 2
```

and so on?

Why does this

```
MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n];
MyFunc[3]

During evaluation of In[31]:= $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>

Out[33]= Hold[MyFunc[3]]
```

cause "iteration" limit error, not recursion limit?

Answer (score 1):

My other answer glossed over some important details.  Here's a second and, I hope, better one:

`SetDelayed` has the attribute `HoldAll` while `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst`.  So, your definition

```
MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n] = 2;
```

is stored with no part evaluated.  Only when you call it, *eg* `MyFunc[3]` is the rhs evaluated, in this case to an expression involving `Set`, `MyFunc[3] = 2`.  Since `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst` this rule is stored with its first argument (*ie* the lhs) unevaluated.  At this stage `MyFunc[3]`, the lhs of the `Set` expression is not re-evaluated.  But if it were, Mathematica would find the rule `MyFunc[3] = 2` and evaluate `MyFunc[3]` to `2` without using the rule with lhs `MyFunc[n_]`.

Your second definition, *ie*

```
MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n];
```

is also stored unevaluated.  However, when you call the function, *eg* `myFunc[3]`, the rhs is evaluated.  The rhs evaluates to `MyFunc[3]` or, if you like, another call to `MyFunc`.  During the evaluation of `MyFunc[3]` Mathematica finds the stored rewrite rule `MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n]` and applies it. Repeatedly.  Note that Mathematica regards this as iteration rather than recursion.

It's not entirely clear to me what evaluating the lhs of an expression might actually mean.  Of course, a call such as `MyFunc[3+4]` will actually lead to `MyFunc[7]` being evaluated, as Mathematica greedily evaluates arguments to function calls.

In fact, when trying to understand what's going on here it might be easier to forget assignment and left- and right-hand sides and remember that *everything is an expression* and that, for example,

```
MyFunc[n_] := MyFunc[n] = 2;
```

is just a way of writing

```
SetDelayed[MyFunc[n_], MyFunc[n] = 2]
```